# SQL select case when clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, case

The following is the query

```
select *,  "Price Range" = 
  CASE 
     WHEN ListPrice =  0 THEN 'Mfg item - not for resale'
     WHEN ListPrice < 50 THEN 'Under $50'
     WHEN ListPrice >= 50 and ListPrice < 250 THEN 'Under $250'
     WHEN ListPrice >= 250 and ListPrice < 1000 THEN 'Under $1000'
     ELSE 'Over $1000'
  END
  FROM Production.Product
      ORDER BY ProductNumber
```

But there is SQL error, missing important words before FROM.

What is the blueprint for us to use `case` if I want to select all the columns ?

Comment: Is there any relation between the two tables `customer` and `Production.Product` because you can't write it the way you wrote.

Comment: You should use the alias `.. AS alais` not `alias = ...` as explained in the below answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try This

```
select *, 
  CASE 
     WHEN ListPrice =  0 THEN 'Mfg item - not for resale'
     WHEN ListPrice < 50 THEN 'Under $50'
     WHEN ListPrice >= 50 and ListPrice < 250 THEN 'Under $250'
     WHEN ListPrice >= 250 and ListPrice < 1000 THEN 'Under $1000'
     ELSE 'Over $1000'
  END AS [Price Range]
  FROM Production.Product
      ORDER BY ProductNumber
```

Answer (score 4):

Put the column name after end, your query is not right, should be

```
SELECT p.ProductName, 
  CASE 
     WHEN ListPrice =  0 THEN 'Mfg item - not for resale'
     WHEN ListPrice < 50 THEN 'Under $50'
     WHEN ListPrice >= 50 and ListPrice < 250 THEN 'Under $250'
     WHEN ListPrice >= 250 and ListPrice < 1000 THEN 'Under $1000'
     ELSE 'Over $1000'
  END AS Price_Range
FROM Product p
```

But is there a link between your Product and Customer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ,  Sorry I thought it is like Sql server, as it valid in SQL Server :(

Comment: @MahmoudGamal: SQL Server also accepts the standard syntax. You should get used to that ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes I know I should stick to the standard syntax, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `alias` should come after the case statement in `Oracle`. Try this,

```
SELECT  *  ,
        CASE 
            WHEN ListPrice =  0 THEN 'Mfg item - not for resale'
            WHEN ListPrice < 50 THEN 'Under $50'
            WHEN ListPrice >= 50 and ListPrice < 250 THEN 'Under $250'
            WHEN ListPrice >= 250 and ListPrice < 1000 THEN 'Under $1000'
            ELSE 'Over $1000'
        END AS "Price Range"
FROM    Production.Product
ORDER BY ProductNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you selecting `from customer`?

```
select *, 
  CASE  
     WHEN ListPrice =  0 THEN 'Mfg item - not for resale' 
     WHEN ListPrice < 50 THEN 'Under $50' 
     WHEN ListPrice >= 50 and ListPrice < 250 THEN 'Under $250' 
     WHEN ListPrice >= 250 and ListPrice < 1000 THEN 'Under $1000' 
     ELSE 'Over $1000' 
  END as [Price Range]
  FROM Production.Product 
      ORDER BY ProductNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
 select *, "Price Range" = 
 CASE 
    WHEN ListPrice =  0 THEN 'Mfg item - not for resale'
    WHEN ListPrice < 50 THEN 'Under $50'
    WHEN ListPrice >= 50 and ListPrice < 250 THEN 'Under $250'
    WHEN ListPrice >= 250 and ListPrice < 1000 THEN 'Under $1000'
 ELSE 'Over $1000'
 END
    FROM Production.Product
    ORDER BY ProductNumber
```